# when hovering on images only show arrow Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, gallery-image, image-preview

I want to show only left/right arrow appear only when hovering the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just remove the css of background color

http://prntscr.com/tp1s0v

or you can assign background color to none

Comment: Thanks Jigs, I want to resize product view gallery image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: in your theme etc/view.xml file you change the size image id product_page_main_image